# How to call suspend function in anylogic?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

1. I create an integer to count the number of assemblies (e.g. `countAssembler`)
2. On exit from FA1 (`countAssembler++;`)
3. Then I have an **event triggered** by a condition such that when the count of assemblies reaches 10 ((`countAssembler==10`)), it suspends the FA1 for two hours using *suspend function*.

**But how do I implement the suspend function? Do you have any ideas?**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note that the suspend function doesn't suspend the assembler, but an item that is currently being processed in the assembler...

have a variable countAssembler count the number of items produced... then

1. on exit you write countAssembler++;
2. on enter delay you write the following:

   if(countAssembler==10){
   self.suspend(agent);
   create_MyDynamicEvent(2, HOUR,agent);
   }
3. on the dynamic event you write:

   assembler.resume(agent);

Don't forget to add the parameter needed in the dynamic event:
[image: dynamic event]

Note that the suspend will start when part 11 starts being assembled, which means that the machine will be suspended for 2 hours + the time between the 10th assembly end and then 11th assembly start... you can fix that easily but im not including it in my answer

Comment: Thank you Felipe for your help. Also, let me know how we can achieve that suspend will start before part 11 enter.